# How to reset the complete document after opening it?

Tags: javascript, pdf, dom-events, reset, acrobat

I want to reset the complete form after opening it.

I have tried this:

```
page.open = this.resetForm();
```

But it doesn't work.
I'm using Acrobat Pro DC.

Comment: Define "reset the complete document". You are currently only resetting the entries in a form.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie after opening the document i want to rest it, so that i get the actual date e.g.

Comment: The question is unclear. There is no such thing as "reset a document", resetting only makes sense in the context of a form.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie okay, with this.resetForm(); i resetting the entries in a form, but how i do this on opening the document?

Comment: By defining an open action. There is a key named `/OpenAction` in the root dictionary (aka Catalog) of a PDF that can hold an action, e.g. a JavaScript action.

Comment: I have looked at my Acrobat version and I have searched the web, but I don't find any way to define an open action manually using Acrobat. I can only do this programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to reset a form when opening:

You can follow these instructions (note that the description is for Acrobat DC; in older versions, it is similar).

1. Open your document in Acrobat.
2. Display the Pages in the Left Hand Panel.
3. Select the Context menu of the first page (or the page which has been specified in the document properties to open).
4. Select *Page Properties…* from the context menu
5. In the dialog which appears, select the *Actions* tab
6. Select Trigger *Page Open*
7. Select Action *Run a JavaScript*
8. Click *Add*
9. In the editor window which appears enter the following code:

If your form is a single page document:

```
this.resetForm() ;
```

If your form is a multiple page document:

```
if (loaded == false) {
this.resetForm() ;
loaded = true ;
}
```

10. Confirm the dialogs until you are back in the document. If you have a single-page document, save it, and you are done.

If you have a multi-page document, proceed as follows:

11. Switch to the Tools window, and select the *JavaScript* Tool
12. Select *Document JavaScripts* in the toolbar
13. In the dialog which opens enter a name for your script, such as `loading`
14. Click *Add…*
15. In the editor window which opens, delete all the selected text.

Then enter this line of code:

```
var loaded = false ;
```

16. Confirm until you are back to the document.
17. Save the document

And that should do it.

Comment: While this solves the problem using a page event, I'm curious to find out how one would define the `/OpenAction` key in the `/Catalog` dictionary using Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie: The reason for the page event instead of a document-level script is that I had issues because a document-level script can run before the whole document has properly loaded. So much for the why… about the implementation, you know more than I do…

Comment: Aha, yes, that's a reasonable reason against the use of the document-level OpenAction.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but it was the first recommended when searching about the subject. So I want to add information for newer versions of Acrobat. At step 7, now it has the option "Reset a form", a new dialog show with a list of fields on page that. Select all or only the fields that you want to reset. Press OK and follow to step 10.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @CarlosH. The suggested procedure works for single-page forms, but for multipage forms, it would not, because every time you get to the first page, the form would get reset. FWIW, having a look at the entry for resetForm() in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation shows how to specify the fields to be reset, whereas other won't.